# How do I define a custom fixer for ALEFix?

Tags: external-command, plugin-ale

I'm trying to use [`:ALEFix`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) to run a fixer that is not pre-defined. For example, I might want to run `foo -a -b index.html` to format `index.html` with options `-a` and `-b`. `foo` does not read files from `stdin`, only by path.

I think the info is all in `:h ale-fix`, but as I'm not very good at Vimscript I haven't managed to do it. How can I?